# How do you justify Adventurers being multiple [Character Classes] instead of everyone being Generalists in fantasy settings?

Tags: magic, warfare, combat, class-structure, high-fantasy

Someday I want to write a fantasy book wherein the MC is a solo adventurer or something similar, thing is when it comes to those types I notice they’re almost all the same…ability/skill-wise especially

It’s practical for everyone to know/do everything, but I am not sure how it could be plausible to write an MC adventurer who’s a specialist and yet a survivor

Let alone justifying almost everyone else being specialists

Most books I have ever read have protagonists who can best be described as anywhere amongst the following: master of none, Jack-of-All-Trades and Renaissance Man

Basically, no specialization, hell they throw away their clothes, armor, weapons & equipment casually and have no favorites let alone named weapons

I am not sure how specific fantasy settings like Warcraft or D&D make it so that characters have Classes with subspecializations

You’d expect anyone who adventures for long periods whether in a group or alone to become a Generalist and throw away their stuff and see it as a burden

I don’t like things being too practical, it makes everyone all look exactly the same after awhile.

Hell, this even applies to works by a single author. Almost all of Robert E. Howard’s protagonists look and act the same as far as I am concerned.

Comment: We answer questions about the rules of your world. We don't dwell into third parties worlds.

Comment: I would say that, just for *one* example, that Alexandre Dumas's Musqueteers saga with its three multi-volume novels counts as "adventuring for long periods". Are you seriously saying that you cannot distinguish between d'Artagnan, Athos, Porthos, and Aramis? One is an old-school nobleman with long-term vision and an overdose of outdated honor, one is a savvy scheming womanising courtier, one is a vain strongman who loves the good life and lives for the moment, and one is a smart, brave, and politically naive outsider. (The descriptions are not in the same order as the names...)

Comment: I'm current voting to close as not about worldbuilding because the question reads like a request to help you write a story or a request to help you understand how to write. We don't do that. D&D and other RPGs are as much about the sociality of friends playing a game as they are about the story, so it's little wonder they're designed to focus on teams and not overpowered individuals. Have you researched anyone in Real Life that might be like what you're looking for? Of course, what you'll find is that behind any successful soloist is a team of supporters.

Comment: Let's add to AlexP's classic reference that most modern stories will bring specialists sometimes so strongly their "class" is almost written on their forehead : Atlantis: The lost Empire (Disney), Stargate SG:1, Avatar (both sci-fi movies and unrelated animated series) Goblin Slayer, Dr Stone, The Lords of the ring, superhero teamup comics... In all these movies and books you'll see specialists, be it demolition men, healers, wizards, scientists, leaders, melee/ranged fighters... And I'm not counting that in almost every good team RPGs all characters have roles with strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Hmm, your question is close... to get closed. You could alleviate some of JBH's issues by making some rewording : Instead of asking how to justify something, ask how it can be in your world : "***How can I entice my adventurers to follow** more specific roles/classes instead of everyone being generalists in my fantasy setting?*". Note that I also rephrased to focus on your world, not any fantasy setting. Indeed, we're not really here to analyze how any world is made , but to improve yours specifically . It'd avoid remarks that you are asking about 3rd party worlds and earn some votes 

Comment: Has anyone pointed you to our [writing.se] site? It might better suite your current battery of story and writing-based questions than here.

Answer (score 1):

In a **tabletop RPG** context, skills can be classified into 'best of party' and 'worst of party' categories. This isn't perfectly clear, of course. There are situations in between.

- With a **'best of party' skill**, the outcome for the group is the best die roll, or only the best will attempt the die roll. Examples would include tracking an enemy in the wilderness, negotiating a deal with a merchant, or brewing a magical potion.
- With a **'worst of party' skill**, the outcome for the group is the worst die roll. Examples include sneaking stealthily past a sentry, riding a skittish horse over uncertain ground, or *not* embarassing the entire party at court.

An adventurer might have decent levels in all the 'worst of party' skills, and excel in a few 'best of party' skills. Such an adventurer might **need sidekicks** from time to time, but it is easier to hire a competent groom today, a competent boatsman next month, a competent clerk after that, than becoming competent in all those skills. The drawback would be that the character has to **share the rewards** with the sidekicks, but perhaps not on an equal basis.

And the character would be vulnerable to betrayal by those sidekicks. If the sidekicks become too reliable and permanent, you have a party rather than a clear protagonist.

Answer (score 0):

You specialize because being really good at one thing in a fight is better than being mediocre at several things. If you are moderately good with the mace, the axe, and the sword, and you are currently wielding a sword, then you are only moderately good overall, and can't beat an expert-level enemy. If you are an expert with the sword, and are currently wielding a sword, then you are an expert overall, and can beat an expert-level enemy.

The same goes for magic. Specialize and become really good at one school of magic, and use that magic for your main damage in a fight, and you'll be more powerful than if you're a generalist.

If you're in a group, the pressure to specialize is even higher because other group members can cover areas that your specialization lacks. A solo adventurer might be well served by learning a little healing magic to close their wounds, in addition to their main damage specialty, because if they get hurt they have no one else to rely on. But in a party you can have a character specialized in healing, and they can heal people's injuries much better than if just every member of the party knew the basics of healing.